# Tables with "varchar(50)" variables into "int" and "float/decimal" variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am trying to convert the columns in my table from varchar(50) into float or Decimal with SQL Server Management Studio. I have managed to do it with something like

```
alter table Miguel.dbo.[2015-2016] alter column FTAG int
```

and it worked well. I can even change it manually in the options of the table from the console. The thing is, I have 3 tables with 50 columns each, and it is a waste of time to check if every column is an integer or a float number and change it manually afterwards. How can I apply a general change to the whole table, so that it automatically recognizes if it is a integer or a float (when the values have decimals).

Comment: So you're after a one click button that will scan your tables, work out the best datatype for each column then apply it?

Comment: Something like that... I don´t know why sql-server assigns my datacolumns as varchar(50)

Comment: *" I don´t know why sql-server assigns my datacolumns as varchar(50)"* it doesn't; that would be whomever designed the database that made that assumption.

Comment: The table was imported from a csv file, I didn´t create it

Answer (score 0):

Use a format file to describe your file to sql server. This is an xml or proprietary formatted file that tells sql server how to map the columns in the file to the columns in your table

You can find a detailed explanation in [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

The overall process is:

- have a table with columns of various data types
- create a format file that describes the csv, field widths, terminators etc, and maps fields to columns (hence supports fields and columns thatbare not in the same order)
- run the import using the formatfile

#### Here's a precis of the MSDN:

Create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Person (
PersonID smallint,
FirstName varchar(25),
LastName varchar(30),
BirthDate Date
);
```

Create a CSV (c:\temp\my.csv):

```
1,Anthony,Grosse,1980-02-23
2,Alica,Fatnowna,1963-11-14
3,Stella,Rosenhain,1992-03-02
```

Create a format file (c:temp\format.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="25" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="30" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="11"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="PersonID" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="FirstName" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="LastName" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="BirthDate" xsi:type="SQLDATE"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Import the data from the CSV with reference to the Format File:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Person   
   FROM 'c:\temp\my.csv'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'c:\temp\format.xml');  
GO
```